# DHXScheduler Save/Get Custom Lightbox Fields

Tags: java, javascript, json, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using DHXScheduler in my JSP application for exam timetabling. I added a fully custom lightbox with my own fields with information about exams.

This is my EventsManager class which saves, creates and gets events. It extends the class DHXEventsManager.

```
public class EventsManager extends DHXEventsManager {

public EventsManager(HttpServletRequest request) {          
    super(request);
}

public Iterable getEvents() {

    Connection conn = null;
    DHXEventsManager.date_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    try {

        conn = SQLHelper.getConnection();
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
        query.append("SELECT * FROM ");
        query.append(TimetableEvent.TBL_EVENTS);
        query.append(" e JOIN ");
        query.append(StudyUnit.TBL_STUDYUNITS);
        query.append(" s ON e.");
        query.append(TimetableEvent.FLD_UNITCODE);
        query.append(" = s.");
        query.append(StudyUnit.FLD_UNITCODE);

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query.toString());

        while (rs.next()) {

            Event e = new Event(); // extends DHXEvent and contains additional fields

            e.setId(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(TimetableEvent.FLD_ID)));
            e.setText(rs.getString(TimetableEvent.FLD_UNITCODE));
            e.setStart_date(rs.getString(TimetableEvent.FLD_STARTDATE));
            e.setEnd_date(rs.getString(TimetableEvent.FLD_ENDDATE));
            e.setUnitCode(rs.getString(StudyUnit.FLD_UNITCODE));
            e.setTitle(rs.getString(StudyUnit.FLD_TITLE));
            e.setYear(rs.getString(StudyUnit.FLD_YEAR));
            e.setSemester(rs.getShort(StudyUnit.FLD_SEMESTER));
            e.setExamLength(rs.getFloat(StudyUnit.FLD_EXAMLENGTH));
            e.setNoOfStudents(rs.getShort(StudyUnit.FLD_NOOFSTUDENTS));
            e.setDepartment(rs.getString(StudyUnit.FLD_DEPARTMENT));
            e.setCredits(rs.getShort(StudyUnit.FLD_CREDITS));
            e.setEvening(rs.getBoolean(StudyUnit.FLD_EVENING));

            events.add(e);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("[EventsManager.getEvents()]: " + e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            SQLHelper.closeConnection(conn);
        }

        DHXEventsManager.date_format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
        return events;
    }

    @Override
    public DHXStatus saveEvent(DHXEv event, DHXStatus status) {
    Connection conn = SQLHelper.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    Event ev = (Event) event;

    try {

        if (status == DHXStatus.UPDATE) {
            pstmt = TimetableEvent.updateEvent(conn, ev);

        } else if (status == DHXStatus.INSERT) {
            System.out.println("SAVE");
            pstmt = TimetableEvent.insertEvent(conn, ev);

        } else if (status == DHXStatus.DELETE) {
            pstmt = TimetableEvent.deleteEvent(conn, event);
        }

        if (pstmt != null) {
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();

            if (rs.next()) {
                event.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                ev.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("[EventsManager.saveEvent() - " + status.name() + "]: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        if (rs != null) SQLHelper.closeResultSet(rs);
        if (pstmt != null) SQLHelper.closePreparedStatement(pstmt);
        if (conn != null) SQLHelper.closeConnection(conn);
    }

    return status;
}

    @Override
public DHXEv createEvent(String id, DHXStatus status) {
    return new Event();
}
}
```

The `Event` class extends `DHXEvent` and contains getters and setters for the additional fields. The problem is that when I am casting from `DHXEv` to `Event`, I am losing the additional fields to null but the saveEvent method only accepts DHXEv as a parameter.

This is `events.jsp` file where the getEvents() method from EventsManager is called to get JSON objects with events.

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json" 
         import="com.dhtmlx.planner.*,servlets.*,events.EventsManager"
%>

<%= getEvents(request) %>
<%!
    String getEvents(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        EventsManager evs = new EventsManager(request);
        return evs.run();
    }
%>
```

This is a sample of what its returning. As you can see it only returns fields from `DHXEv` object i.e. `id, start_date, end_date and text`.

```
{id:7, text:CIS3087, end_date:03/27/2014 13:00, start_date:03/27/2014 10:00}
```

How can I add those additional fields to the JSON object i.e. have an object with studyunit title, department, etc?

This is the some relevant client-side code for the scheduler.. its configuration and the save_form() and show_lightbox methods:

```
scheduler.config.api_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick = true;
scheduler.config.details_on_create = true;
scheduler.config.first_hour = "8";  
scheduler.config.last_hour = "22";
scheduler.config.drag_lightbox = true;
scheduler.config.show_loading = true;
scheduler.config.mark_now = true;

scheduler.init('scheduler_here', new Date(), "week");
scheduler.load("events.jsp", "json");

var dp = new dataProcessor("events.jsp");
dp.init(scheduler);

function save_form() {
      var ev = scheduler.getEvent(scheduler.getState().lightbox_id);

      ev.text = html("studyunit_code").value;
      ev.start_date = setDate("start_date", "starttime");
      ev.end_date = setDate("start_date", "endtime");

      scheduler.endLightbox(true, html("custom_form"));

      $("#form1").submit(); // submits all the other fields and saves them to a db table
}

scheduler.showLightbox = function(id) {

    var ev = scheduler.getEvent(id);
    scheduler.startLightbox(id, html("custom_form"));

    html("studyunit_code").value = ev.text;
    html("studyunit_code").focus();
    html("studyunit_title").value = ev.studyunit_title;

    var startDate = ev.start_date;
    getDate(startDate, "start_date", "starttime");

    var endDate = ev.end_date;
    getDate(endDate, "start_date", "endtime");              
};
```

I'm guessing its just a small modification that I have to make to get the fields in the JSON object and show them in the lightbox.

Do you have any idea of how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: On your save_form method, just add ev.studyunit = '1' you can add as many ev.whatever = foo, if you're using a custom form for the scheduler you need to have a field called studyinit so it saves it on the database and be able to retrieve it when you consult an event.

Answer (score -1):

Please, make sure that additional fields in Event class are public. DHXEventsManager uses Class.getFields() to get event properties. If property is private then it's not available in generated JSON.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).